# How do I prevent my image overlay from extending past the width of my image?

Tags: html, css

I am working on implementing an overlay with text over my images. The text is centered but the overlay extends past the width of the image. I am not sure what I am overlooking in terms of restricting the overlay. Currently the background for main trending article extends the full width of the screen while the background for the two trending articles extends a little past the width of the image.

```css
img.rounded {
  border-radius: 5%; /* Use 50% to create a circular shape */
}

figure {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); /* Opaque background color */
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0; /* Initially hidden */
  transition: opacity 0.3s ease-in-out;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: inline-block;
  justify-content: center;
}

figure:hover figcaption {
  opacity: 1; /* Show on hover */
}
```

```html
<section id="trending">
  <h1>Trending News</h1>
  <!--Main trending article-->
  <figure>
    <a href = "article.html">
      <img src="./images/ja.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width:50%" class = "rounded">
      <figcaption>Ja Suspended Again</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
</section>
<section id="twoTrending">
  <figure>
    <a href = basketball.html>
      <img src="./images/bron.jpg" alt="Trulli" style="width: 80%" class="rounded">
      <figcaption>Lebron announces retirement.</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
  <!--Second trending article-->
  <figure>
    <a href = "basketball.html">
      <img src="./images/bron.jpg" alt="Landscape" style="width: 80%" class="rounded">
      <figcaption>Another Lebron article.</figcaption>
    </a>
  </figure>
</section>
```

I have tried using the overflow: hidden which I have usually had success with.

Comment: Well your `<figcaption>` is absolutely positioned against its first positioned ancestor, which is your `<figure>` in this case. Your CSS tells it to take 100% of the space. Your images, on the other hand, only take 50% and 80%. That's the caption overflows.

Comment: Quickest fix is to align the widths of your images and your captions. Why do you have different widths for the images instead of them simply taking the entire available space?